# Combining 2 datasets in a single plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have two columns of data, `f.delta` and `g.delta` that I  would like to produce a scatter plot of in R.

Here is how I am doing it.

```
plot(f.delta~x, pch=20, col="blue")
points(g.delta~x, pch=20, col="red")
```

The problem is this: the values of `f.delta` vary from 0 to -7; the values of `g.delta` vary from 0 to 10.

When the plot is drawn, the y axis extends from 1 to -7. So while all the `f.delta` points are visible, any `g.delta` point that has y>1 is cut-off from view.

How do I stop R from automatically setting the ylims from the data values. Have tried, unsuccessfully, various combinations of `yaxt`, `yaxp`, `ylims`.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anjan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Gavin's excellent answer, I also thought I'd mention that another common idiom in these cases is to create an empty plot with the correct limits and then to fill it in using `points`, `lines`, etc.

Using Gavin's example data:

```
with(df,plot(range(x),range(f.delta,g.delta),type = "n"))
points(f.delta~x, data = df, pch=20, col="blue")
points(g.delta~x, data = df, pch=20, col="red")
```

The `type = "n"` causes `plot` to create only the empty plotting window, based on the range of x and y values we've supplied. Then we use `points` for both columns on this existing plot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell R what the limits of the data are and pass that as argument `ylim` to `plot()` (note the argument is `ylim` not `ylims`!). Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(f.delta = runif(10, min = -7, max = 0),
                 g.delta = runif(10, min = 0, max = 10),
                 x = rnorm(10))

ylim <- with(df, range(f.delta, g.delta)) ## compute y axis limits

plot(f.delta ~ x, data = df, pch = 20, col = "blue", ylim = ylim)
points(g.delta ~ x, data = df, pch = 20, col = "red")
```

Which produces

[image]